# sum values base duplicate values in dict - python

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I have a dict as below:

```
dict_data = {
  "NAME": ['A', 'B', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'C'],
  "VALUE": [100, 200 , 100 , 200, 300, 300]
}
```

How to sum values from above dict if NAME duplicate
output:

```
NAME: A
VALUE: 200
NAME: B
VALUE: 400
NAME: C
VALUE: 600
```

or output to with list:

```
[A, B, C]
[200, 400, 600]
```

i using as below:

```
data = dict.fromkeys(dict_data['NAME'], 0) #create a new dict from value "NAME" of DICT_DATA
for NAME, VALUE in zip(dict_data['NAME'], dict_data['VALUE']):
  data[NAME] += value # Dict NAME A + Dict Name A,... similar to B and C
for key,value in data.items():
 print(list(key))
 print(list(value))
```

Comment: what have you tried ?

Comment: hi @azro, i have tried and it's not worked, but i have using dict.fromkeys as above and it worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without extra imports.

Use class method `fromkeys` to set default values

```
d = dict.fromkeys(dict_data['NAME'], 0)
for k, v in zip(dict_data['NAME'], dict_data['VALUE']):
    d[k] += v

print(d)
```

or, more verbosely, with the instance method `setdefault`

```
d = {}
for k, v in zip(dict_data['NAME'], dict_data['VALUE']):
    d.setdefault(k, 0)
    d[k] += v
```

These solutions are meant to reply to the comment *"If you don't use defualtdict, you can not wtite `res[k] += v`"*

Answer (score 2):

Use a `collections.defaultdict` then iterate and sum by grouping on key

```
dict_data = {"NAME": ["A", "B", "A", "B", "C", "C"], "VALUE": [100, 200, 100, 200, 300, 300]}
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(int)
for key, value in zip(dict_data['NAME'], dict_data['VALUE']):
    result[key] += value
```

```
for key, value in result.items():
    print("NAME", key)
    print("VALUE", value)

keys, values = zip(*result.items())
print(keys)
print(values)
```

```
NAME A
VALUE 200
NAME B
VALUE 400
NAME C
VALUE 600

('A', 'B', 'C')
(200, 400, 600)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `defaultdict` with `zero` in start.

```
dict_data = {
  "NAME": ['A', 'B', 'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'C'],
  "VALUE": [100, 200 , 100 , 200, 300, 300]
}

from collections import defaultdict

# res = defaultdict(lambda : 0)
res = defaultdict(int)

for k,v in zip(dict_data['NAME'], dict_data['VALUE']):
    res[k] += v
    
print(list(res.keys()))
print(list(res.values()))
```

Output:

```
['A', 'B', 'C']
[200, 400, 600]
```

Comment: Hi I'mahdi, what "lambda : 0" mean ?
If value not 100 , 200 , 300 instead 1234, 1234 , 2345 ,2345 ? i think lambda : 0 not correct

Comment: @ĐặngLực `lambda: 0` is just a function that always returns 0. It is used for the first time a key is accessed. It is equivalent to `int`

Comment: @ĐặngLực, You can create `dict` and set what is type of elements like : `defaultdict(list)` or `defaultdict(int)` or `defaultdict(lambda : 0)`. If you don't use defualtdict, you can not wtite `res[k] += v` but when use `defaultdict`, you can suppose you have key and add value to `zero`.

Comment: @ĐặngLực, You can start from `10` instead of `zero` with : `defaultdict(lambda : 10)`

Comment: Hi @I'mahdi, if i have add one more row on dict_data  "NAME2": ['W', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'Y', 'Y']. Can i use defaultdict ?
OUTPUT: 
```
[A, B, C]
[200, 400, 600]
[W,T,Y]
```

Comment: @ĐặngLực, with `NAME2` -> what is desired output?

Comment: @I'mahdi
output
`[A, B, C] [200, 400, 600] [W,T,Y]`

Comment: @ĐặngLực, check duplicated on `NAME1`?

Comment: @I'mahdi
Yes, Check duplicated on `NAME1`

Comment: try this: ```dict_data = {
  "NAME": ['A', 'B', 'A' , 'B' , 'C' , 'C'],
  "VALUE": [100, 200 , 100 , 200, 300, 300],
    "NAME2": ['W', 'T', 'W', 'T', 'Y', 'Y']
}

from collections import defaultdict

res = defaultdict(int)
res2 = {}

for a,b,c in zip(dict_data['NAME'], dict_data['VALUE'], dict_data['NAME2']):
    res[a] += b
    res2[a] = c
    
print(list(res.keys()))
print(list(res.values()))
print(list(res2.values()))```